# Set paragraph skip for each section

Tags: sectioning, parskip

I am using the `parskip` package to remove indentation before each paragraph in my document. However, for certain sections of the document, I want to use the default paragraph indentation style (i.e. I want to disable `parskip` for that section only). Is there an easy way to do this?

If at all possible, I would like to be able to switch between using `parskip` and using `indentfirst` by section.

Comment: `\begingroup \parindent=<length> ... [text goes here] ... \endgroup` (where `<length>` is something like, say, `18pt`).

Comment: Could I make some sort of reusable "class" for indentation that I can just specify with a single tag at the start of each section?

Comment: You can write `\parindent=<length>` [pretty much] anywhere you want and set it to `0pt` or `1239pt` or etc.; but if you want it for 'certain sections', then I'd use a group or define an environment (with `\newenvironment`. Since commands like `\section` don't naturally form groups, I think it is a bad idea to try to hook into them so things happen 'automatically'. Besides, using groups or environments helps keep your code comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip, lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indentpars}[1][18pt]{%
  % indentfirst.sty is the following two lines:
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
  \@afterindenttrue
  % Now we set \parindent:
  \parindent=#1\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Default}
\lipsum

\section{Indent Pars}
\indentpars[3cm]
\lipsum

\section{Noindent Pars}
\parindent0pt

\lipsum

\begingroup % if doing this often, then an environment is the way to go
  Indent pars again:
  \indentpars[18pt]%
  \lipsum[1-10]
\endgroup

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be curious to learn why indenting and not-indenting paragraphs is needed. Non-indented paragraphs can confuse a reader, so mixing them with 'regular' paragraphs is probably ill-advised for most types of documents.

Comment: @pzp How do you separate non-indented paragraphs? If you use a blank line then consider the poor reader when a paragraph ends with a complete line and also ends the page, how is anyone able to tell that the first text on the next page is a new paragraph?